# How do I increase the max size of files that can be uploaded with AuraClient?

Tags: upload, fileupload

We are trying to upload files with the AuraClient.

Getting error:  auraclientinputexception   max message parameter length.
The limit is even smaller in our sandbox server (3MB or so)
[image]

Is there a way to increase this limit in the production server?
Is there a way to increase limit in a sandbox server?

Comment: Is your ask about custom lightning upload?

Comment: I'm not familiar with custom lightning upload. I"m not the Dev, I'm the PdM

Answer (score 1):

`lightning:uploadFile` has the higher 2GB limit for file uploads. The downside is that you don't get to read the file beforehand, but you do get the `contentDocumentId` value that you can use to perform other operations with the file afterwards. This component isn't available in LWR Digital Experiences, unfortunately, but works fine in most other places, including Flows, the UI, and non-LWR Digital Experiences.

Comment: I think you mean `lightning:fileUpload` (or its LWC counterpart, `lightning-file-upload`) 

Comment: @JeffKranz I did, actually. Missing my morning ☕, lol. Thanks for letting me know.